# How to establish navigation from xml menu to a xml form with odoo 16?

Tags: python, xml, odoo, erp

I've downloaded an odoo 16 module , with some models and views, I added a model named consultation and I added a form to create a consultation  , and I've tried to add the  the form to the menu in order to navigate to the form :
this is the form where I can add another consultation :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<odoo>
    <data>
        <record id="view_consultation_form" model="ir.ui.view">
            <field name="name">consultation.form</field>
            <field name="model">consultation</field>
            <field name="arch" type="xml">
                <form string="Consultation Form">
                    <sheet>
                        <group>
                            <field name="id" readonly="1"/>
                            <field name="année_soumission"/>
                            <field name="ajouté_par"/>
                            <field name="date_publication"/>
                            <field name="date_limite"/>
                            <field name="heure_limite"/>
                        </group>
                    </sheet>
                </form>
            </field>
        </record>

        <record id="action_consultation_form" model="ir.actions.act_window">
            <field name="name">Consultation</field>
            <field name="res_model">consultation</field>
            <field name="view_mode">form</field>
        </record>

        <menuitem id="menu_consultation" name="Consultation" action="action_consultation_form"/>
    </data>
</odoo>
```

this is the menu where I  can navigate between the files :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<odoo>

    <menuitem id="estate_menu_root" name="Estates"/>

    <menuitem id="estate_property_first_level_menu" name="Estates" parent="estate_menu_root" action="estate_property_action"/>

    <menuitem id="estate_property_settings_first_level_menu" name="Settings" parent="estate_menu_root">
        <menuitem id="estate_type_menu_action" name="Types" action="estate_property_type_action"/>
        <menuitem id="estate_tag_menu_action" name="Tags" action="estate_property_tag_action"/>
        <!-- <menuitem id="estate_offer_menu_action" name="Offers" action="estate_property_offer_action"/> -->
        <menuitem id="consultation_menu_action" name="Consultation" action="action_consultation_form"/>
    </menuitem>
</odoo>
```